# Powerbuilder Datawindow textbox does not word-wrap

Tags: powerbuilder, word-wrap, datawindow

I am trying to display a long word like a URL in a text box.  Setting Vertical Scroll and Auto Vertical Scroll does not do the job.  The line will be cut off.

Comment: Powerbuilder Datawindows won't wrap words without any spaces in them. Your best bet is to make the field long enough to display the urls.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SingleLineEdit to display such kind of data, you should use MultiLineEdit control.
But make sure that HScrollBar and AutoHScroll properties are unchecked, otherwise it won't work.